# Go: get a broken JSON field name

Tags: json, go

Suppose I'm parsing a JSON input into a structure like this:

```
type Person struct {
        Name string `json:"name"`
        Age  uint   `json:"age"`         
}
```

and pass erroneous data (`string` instead of `int`):

```
var person Person
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"name": "Dilbert", "age": "unknown"}`), &person)
```

This is what I can extract from the error:

```
// Error json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type uint
fmt.Printf("Error %v\n", err) 

// Unexpected value: unknown
jerr := err.(*json.UnmarshalTypeError)
fmt.Printf("Unexpected value: %s\n", (*jerr).Value)

// Expected type: uint
fmt.Printf("Unexpected type: %v\n", (*jerr).Type)
```

I'd like to report also which field is erroneous (`age`, in my case), is that possible?

(I understand, that, for example, when you parse an array or a scalar value, that's not applicable, but still, I hope there might be some workaround or trick for the case of objects.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is currently not supported.

There is an [accepted issue](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6716) for this. It seems to be not trivial to implement (see quote from the ticket below) but hopefully it comes with Go 1.3.

> Made slightly inconvenient to implement because by the time the error
>   is generated the decoder is looking at the field value itself, not the
>   struct that contains the field. The relevant code doesn't even know
>   that it's decoding into a struct field. There are a few ways to get
>   around this but they are non-trivial.